# 3 Column full height CSS layout with header and footer for web application

Tags: css

I think my question deviates from the typical 3 column issues that most people have trouble with.  I am looking for something like this:

3 columns with header and footer.  This will be a web application where the entire page will NOT scroll unless the user has a very small vertical browser height.  I want the left sidebar to stick to the left side of the screen and be a minimum width in pixels, the right sidebar to stick to the right side of the screen and be a minimum width in pixels, and the center content portion to fill the space in between the two sidebars completely but have a minimum width in pixels as well.  This central content portion would have its own scroll bar should the content go beyond its height.

The main issue I am having is that I cant seem to find any 3 column layouts that stick the sidebars right and left while allowing me to specify a minimum width of the center content.  The closest I have found to what I want is http://pmob.co.uk/temp/3colfixedtest_explained.htm but I cant for the life of me get the center content area to have a minimum width!

Comment: Where were you applying the min-width? I just tried and it works fine. Try adding min-width to the **outer** id.

Comment: You're pushing the edge of what you can accomplish with just html/css here... what kind of support do you want your page to have? And as I understand the left col header and footer need to be always visible unless the height doesn't allow it?

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper {
    display: block;
    width: 100%; /* define your max site width here */
    margin: 0 auto; /* centers the container, keep if not 100% wide */
    padding: 0;
    clear: both;
}
.container {
    display: inline-block;
}
.bar-left,
.bar-right,
.bar-mid {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100% !important;
}
.bar-left, .bar-right {
    width: 20%; /* sidebar width */
    overflow: hidden; /* hide extra content */
}
.bar-mid {
    width: 60%; /* main content width */
    overflow: scroll; /* add scrollbar for extra content */
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="bar-left">
            // stuff
        </div>

        <div class="bar-mid">
            // stuff
        </div>

        <div class="bar-right">
            // stuff
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then what you should do is use a `media query` to adjust the elements' widths as needed. There is a plugin to make media queries work in browsers without native support [here](http://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/).

Using the css declaration `min-width` is nice, but doesn't play well with IE.

Comment: Note, they don't take up 100% of the browser height automatically, but they will expand up to that. I'm tired and signing off, perhaps someone else can debug my css for you.

Answer (score 0):

Working sample here:

[3 columns layout with header and footer 100% height flex](https://jsfiddle.net/t9snzp50/)

```css
  html,body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; }
    body {
        height:100%;
        min-height: 100%;
        background: #222;
        color: #fff;
        position:relative;
        font-family: Arial
    }
    center{
      padding: 15px; box-sizing: border-box; color: #fff; font-weight: bold;
    }
    #header {
        height:70px;
        width:100%;
        top:0px;
        left:0px;
        background: #f60;
        position:absolute;
    }
    #footer {
        height:50px;
        width:100%;
        bottom:0px;
        left:0px;
        background: #f60;
        position:absolute;
    }
    #content {
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        height:100%;
        padding: 0px 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .full-height {    
      height: 100%;  
      width: 100%;
      padding-top: 70px;  /* header height */
      display: flex;
      overflow: auto;
    }
    .col{
      margin-bottom: 120px; /* header height + footer height */
      flex: 1;
      padding: 20px;  
      overflow: auto;
    }
    .col2 p{ 
      float: left; width: 90%; 
      margin: 1% 5% 1% 5%; 
      padding: 10px; 
      color: #f60;  
      background: #fff; 
      border: 1px solid #f60; 
      box-sizing: border-box;
      text-align: center;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .col1 {
      max-width: 150px;
      background: #5c5;   
    }
    .col2 {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      max-width: auto;  
      background: #eee; 
      color: #000; 
    }
    .col3 {
      max-width: 150px;   
      background: #5c5; 
    }
```

```html
  <body>
      <div id="header">
        <center> HEADER </center>
      </div>
          <div id="content">
              <div class="full-height">
          <div class="col col1">
              <h2>Column 1</h2>
              <p>Hello World</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col col2">        
              <p>3 column layout with footer and header fixed height</p>
              <p>3 column layout with footer and header fixed height</p>
              <p>3 column layout with footer and header fixed height</p>
              <p>3 column layout with footer and header fixed height</p>        
              <p>3 column layout with footer and header fixed height</p>
              <p>3 column layout with footer and header fixed height</p>
              <p>3 column layout with footer and header fixed height</p>
              <p>3 column layout with footer and header fixed height</p>
              <p>3 column layout with footer and header fixed height</p>
              <p>3 column layout with footer and header fixed height</p>
              <p>3 column layout with footer and header fixed height</p>
              <p>3 column layout with footer and header fixed height</p>
              <p>3 column layout with footer and header fixed height</p>
              <p>3 column layout with footer and header fixed height</p>
              <p>3 column layout with footer and header fixed height</p>
              <p>3 column layout with footer and header fixed height</p>
              <p>3 column layout with footer and header fixed height</p>
              <p>3 column layout with footer and header fixed height</p>
              <p>3 column layout with footer and header fixed height</p>
              <p>3 column layout with footer and header fixed height</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col col3">
              <h2>Column 3</h2>
              <p>Some other text..</p>
              <p>Some other text..</p>
            </div>
        </div>
          </div>
      <div id="footer"> <center>FOOTER</center> </div>
  </body>
```